# how do I add todays date plus 7 days in a cell with script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the a script to send emails and place a "Email_Sent" in a column to stop re-sends, what I an trying to do is have it enter todays date plus 7 days instead of "Email_Sent" so I can use if `date = Today()` for reminders this is the bit I am trying to change no avail this is what I have and the second snippet is what I need but work:

Working:

```
if (emailSent !== "EMAIL_SENT" && Send == "TRUE") {
var subject = 'Your Movie Link';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messagebody);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 8).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
```

Change to this but not working:

```
if (emailSent == Today()) {
var subject = 'Your Movie Link';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messagebody);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(Today()+7);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

To create a date after 7 days from today:

```
const dt = new Date()
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7)
```

To use the following solution, you need to make sure that `emailSent` is a date object. Go to the sheet and use `=isdate(A1)`. The latter will return `TRUE` if the value of `A1` is indeed a `date` object. If it is a date object, then you can create a `new Date()` object. Namely, if `emailSent` is a date in your sheet, then you should be able to do: `new Date(emailSent)`.

**Solution:**

```
function SendEmails() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Send Email');
  var lastRow =sheet.getLastRow();
  
  var startRow = 2; 
  var numRows = lastRow-1; 

  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5000);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
   var row = data[i];
   var emailAddress = row[1];
   var Name = row[5];
   var Amount = row[6];
   var message = row[7]; 
   var emailSent = row[8];
   var subject = "Reminder fom spreadsheet";
 messagebody = message.replace("{Name}",Name).replace("{Amount}",Amount)
ssTimeZone = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSpreadsheetTimeZone();

const dt = new Date();
if (Utilities.formatDate(new Date(emailSent), ssTimeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd') == Utilities.formatDate(dt, ssTimeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd')) {
dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 7);  
var subject = 'Your Movie Link';
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, messagebody);
sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(dt, ssTimeZone, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));

      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I am getting TypeError: Date is not a constructor

Comment: Error on line 25 
const dt = new Date();

Comment: please check your script if you have any other code that uses the word `Date`. Then change that variable to another name.

Comment: I did have a date variable, removed it, got no error but no mail send

Comment: could it be something with the date column format which I have set to 10/5/2020

Comment: this is a link to the sheet its on the send email sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19BLF3VDpAJcVUYZHzjFqKSlyCinyGDXyfTOjKmSyivE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnnyCardel check my updated complete solution. Consider accepting it and voting up if it solved your issue :)

Comment: If I have if "(emailSent !== "")" it sends  but with " if (emailSent == dt) " it doesn´t

Comment: @JohnnyCardel run the script again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222529/discussion-between-johnny-cardel-and-marios).